# CPLEX: not enough memory

Tags: cplex, opl

I am running a MILP (OPL) on CPLEX 12.9.0 and i have an error "Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: notenough memory".

I tried to run a model on 32 GB of RAM system but an error still occured.

Now, I am not sure that cause is coding or not ? I really need help. Thank you.

These are my attacth files.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in `ct19`: You have this:

```
ct19: forall(p in plant, k1 in truck, k2 in truck : k1 != k2, j1 in jobs, j2 in jobs) //only one tuck can load RMC at the same plant/time
     {
        ...
        forall(p in plant, k1 in truck, k2 in truck : k1 != k2, j1 in jobs, j2 in jobs)
           ...
     }
```

You have nested these two `forall` statements. This will result in a *large* number of combinations of all these indices. I guess you don't want the second `forall` to be nested into the first one but to be it on the same level:

```
ct19: forall(p in plant, k1 in truck, k2 in truck : k1 != k2, j1 in jobs, j2 in jobs) 
     {
        ...
     }
ct19_2:
        forall(p in plant, k1 in truck, k2 in truck : k1 != k2, j1 in jobs, j2 in jobs) {
         ...
     }
```

Note that some other constraints seem to suffer from the same issue.